# Can't find matplotlib.pyplot to import?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the following code on my mac running python 3.6

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I know I have already installed pip so this shouldn't happen.

I think this has something to do with what kind of python I am running? When I run python on my terminal it says I'm running python 3.6 but /usr/bin/python says I'm running 2.7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This just means you have multiple versions of python running and /usr/bin/python points to a python 2.7 binary.  Without any other information on your setup, I would blindly guess you have /usr/bin/python3 pointing to a python 3 binary, so try running `python3 -m myscript.py`

Comment: I got the following message `/anaconda3/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'myscript.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myscript')`

Comment: Remove the `-m`, sorry that was for something else.

Comment: I got `python3: can't open file 'myscript.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`